# Why is this brightness adjustment not getting vectorized in Clang?

Tags: c, clang, compiler-optimization

I tried compiling this code,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct rgb {
  int r, g, b;
};

void adjust_brightness(struct rgb *picdata, size_t len, int adjustment) {
  // assume adjustment is between 0 and 255.
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    picdata[i].r += adjustment;
    picdata[i].g += adjustment;
    picdata[i].b += adjustment;
  }
}
```

on OSX using this command,

```
$ cc -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -c -std=c99 -O3 brightness.c
brightness.c:13:3: remark: loop not vectorized: unsafe dependent memory operations in loop [-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize]
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  ^
```

Can someone explain what is unsafe and dependent here? I'm learning about SIMD, and this was explained at the most obvious use for SIMD. I was hoping to learn how the compiler would generated SIMD instructions for a simple example. In my head, I expect the compiler to maybe instead of incrementing by 1, it would increment by enough to put the loop body into vector registers?

Do I misunderstand?

Comment: Not sure if related, but `i` could overflow since `len` is `size_t` (and signed overflow is UB in C). Make `i` a `size_t` and try it.

Comment: Or maybe its the arithmetic on `r`, `g`, and `b` that might be the problem. If `r`, `g`, and `b` were unsigned types, that might make a difference.

Comment: Sizes that aren't a power of 2 (such as `3 * sizeof(int)`) might cause problems.

Comment: Thanks all. @ColonelThirtyTwo, thanks for pointing that out, it was a coding oversight. It doesn't help my compiler vectorize unfortunately.

Comment: @dreamlax, I don't follow your suggestion, could you elaborate?

Comment: @o11c, I tried using an rgba struct, but I have the same problem.

Comment: @SinclairCombra: I just mean changing the `struct rgb { int r, g, b; };`  to `struct rgb { unsigned r, g, b; };` ... I'm not sure whether that will help or whether you require `r`, `g` and `b` to be signed types, but "overflow" arithmetic is only defined in C for unsigned types. Although, whether the C standard influences the compilers decision to vectorise loops I dunno.

Comment: Interesting, if I pack the ARGB components in memory as bytes, and the use a function like `void adjust_brightness(unsigned char* picdata, int len, unsigned char adjustment)`, clang does vectorize. I guess it just hasn't been taught my dumbass way of adjust image brightness :)